# AudioKit doesn't show all the input & output devices available on my Mac

Tags: swift, audio, avaudiosession, audiokit, avaudioengine

Lately I've been engaged in building audio apps using Swift's AudioKit library. I'm trying to build a simple test app where I can choose the input and output device independently and connect the two, so I can listen to my microphone in real time. My target destinations are Mac Catalyst, iPad and iOS.

In order to list the devices, I'm calling the `AudioKit` static class directly:

```
var availableInputDevices: [Device] { AudioEngine.inputDevices } 
var availableOutputDevices: [Device] { AudioEngine.outputDevices }
```

The issue is that these methods only return the selected audio device on my Mac, instead of returning all of the available devices. I've also noticed that by setting only the Mac as the target destination, AudioKit uses different methods entirely.

I've also tried to use the `Settings.session.availableInputs` and `Settings.session.availableOutputs` properties, which I found by reading the **InputDeviceDemo** on the AudioKit's Cookbook, however they return the same devices.

It's also important to notice that a lot of the questions on StackOverflow use old AudioKit versions, therefore the solutions are not accurate. That's why I decided to open this question.

Can someone with more experience give me more info on how this works and if what I want to do is even possible using AudioKit?

Thanks a lot in advance =)

Comment: "Mac Catalyst, iPad and iOS" -- As far as I know, AudioKit will only be using `AVAudioSession`/`AVAudioEngine` APIs, which generally just return the default device(s), I believe

Comment: I've never used Mac Catalyst, but iPhone style OSes don't have the concept of audio devices that you can select between. At most you can set the `multiRoute` audio session category and (hopefully) be presented with a single device containing all your connected audio devices. You can surely still playthrough, however this is easier if you target `macOS`.